# How can I talk in chat without talking?

Tags: support, chat

I posted this here because my Meta Stack Exchange account is also suspended.

I already miss being in Code Golf that I'm currently in their main room, and what I want to do is to send messages in chat, but now I learned something from a now-deleted question of mine in Meta Stack Exchange. No matter if I switch the parent site while the original parent has my account suspended, I still can't talk saying I'm suspended.

Having no options left, I need some advice. How can I talk in chat without talking?

Comment: I'll be definitely upset if this account gets suspended as well.

Comment: "How can I talk in chat without talking?" Can you be more clear? If you're attempting to circumvent a suspension, that's usually a bad idea. If you disagree with the suspension, you can use the [Contact](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form.

Comment: @Mast I already did it but I didn't hear back, though I did say I'm somewhat of a sockpuppet, so I'm sure I'm not getting the suspension removed. I'm not really trying to circumvent all that much, I'm still learning how the network works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A suspension is never issued casually or without prior warning.

A suspension is a sanction for misbehavior. Trying to circumvent such a suspension can and will have consequences, up to and including deletion of the account. Suspension means, amongst other things, not being allowed to participate fully (or to the extent that the archived reputation points permit). That includes participating in chats.

You are suspended, do your time, think about what got you suspended, come back afterwards.